# iOS switch camera with UIImagePickerController custom camera overlay view

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there a simple way to switch from front to back camera using a custom button on a UIImagePickerController camera overlay view without resorting to using the AVCapture framework?

Answer (score 0):

Hook the overlay view to the class in which you're writing the UIImagePickerController's code by selecting the File's Owner box in the overlay view, going to the Identity Inspector, and adding the class name that the overlay is attaching to. Then, hook the button from the overlay view to the new class with an IBAction. In the IBAction method, you can use the cameraDevice options from the UIImagePickerController class to switch camera views.

```
- (IBAction)switchToFrontCamera:(id)sender {

    self.imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;


}

- (IBAction)switchToBackCamera:(id)sender {

    self.imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;


}
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Didn't work for me. The method is called while the UIImagePickerController is shown and simply nothing happens.

Comment: @Mercurial not sure why it wouldn't be working for you. It is currently working in my project for iOS 7.1 through 8.4.

Comment: A rather strange bug. I got it working the next day. I'm still not sure what happened.